# How to conditionally control/stop data-toggle in Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, haml

For a simple listed item with a `data-toggle`, I was just wondering how to conditionally stop a `data-toggle`.

```
%li{'data-toggle'="modal", 'data-target'='#myModal'}
```

I am looking for something like:

```
%li{'data-toggle'="admin"?"modal":"", 'data-target'='#myModal'}
```

Where admin is an angularJS variable. Just wondering if something like this is possible. I tried the above code and it doesn't not work as expected.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know the specifics of the HAML syntax within an Angular context, but there are a number of ways you can do this in HTML. I'm sure the same concepts would apply when translated to HAML.

#### interpolation

```
<li data-toggle="{{admin ? 'modal' : ''}}" data-target="#myModal">
```

#### ng-attr

```
<li ng-attr-data-toggle="{{admin ? 'modal' : ''}}" data-target="#myModal">
```

#### ng-if

```
<li ng-if="admin"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<li ng-if="!admin" data-toggle=""      data-target="#myModal">
```